# Is there to run only part of requests in Postman?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

We have a lot of API level automated tests written as collections of requests in Postman.

We have a script to run all collections in automated manner.

Is there a way to label/run only subset of requests e.g. with some label e.g. as smoke suite, without copying requests to new collection(s) and run then explicitly (as this yields the need to maintain same tests in 2 places...)?

There might be labels, groups or some script that skips the request is env variable is set...

Comment: There's got to be a better way to do this than create folders that are largely redundant. Maybe [version control](https://learning.postman.com/docs/collaborating-in-postman/version-control-for-collections/)? But it really feels like there should be a feature where one could disable a query based upon some environment variable, filter queries to run in Runner or something like that.

Comment: add an exaple https://www.getpostman.com/collections/73e771fe61f7781f8598

Comment: just press ctrol+o to import and choose link , and use that link

Answer (score 1):

you can create folders and organize test like

1. smoke_and_regression
2. smoke_only etc

you can specify which folder to run using --folder arguent when using newman as command line tool

you can also control the execution flow using **postman.setNextRequest** .

and also you can run newman as an npm module.

you just need to write a logic to read the collection file and get all folder names containing "smoke" for eg and pass it as an array

```
const newman = require('newman'); // require newman in your project

 

// call newman.run to pass `options` object and wait for callback
newman.run({
    collection: require('./sample-collection.json'),
    reporters: 'cli',
    folder: folders
}, function (err) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    console.log('collection run complete!');
});
```

### Just update for the comments:

in old and new UI you can select which folder to execute in collection runner

[image]

Comment: @Rob that was there in previous versions also :)

Comment: in collection runner you can seelct and deselect which request or collections you want to run

Comment: yup you can select folder in postman collection runner ui in old application also

Comment: you can downlaod previous version at https://dl.pstmn.io/download/version/7.36.5/osx64

Comment: please  do accept or upvote if it helped in anyways

Comment: added that to the answer

Comment: It's nice that you've expanded the answer, but it doesn't get to the root of the problem, that we're not looking for a way to run a folder, but rather a way to flag a particular request to run based upon some environment variable (or something like that) such as API version, host name, etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Get all requests in the collection:

**you can also get information about all the requests in a collection by using :**

```
https://api.getpostman.com/collections/{{collection_UUID}}
```

**to get uuid and api key goto :**

```
https://app.getpostman.com
```

**Now for generating api key >**

goto account settings > api key and generate api key.

to get collection uuid goto specific workspace and collection and copy the uuid part from url:

[image]

### Now in your collection

**Rename all requests as:**

```
get user details [Regression][Smoke][Somethingelse]
get account details [Regression]
```

### Then Create a new request called initial request and keep it as the first request in your collection:

**url:**  https://api.getpostman.com/collections/8xxxxtheuuidyoucopied

**authorization:**  apikey-header : key: X-Api-Key and value: yourapikey

**test-script** :

```
pm.environment.unset("requestToRun")
reqeustlist = pm.response.json().collection.item.map((a) => a.name)
requestToRun = reqeustlist.filter((a) => a.includes(pm.environment.get("tag")))
let val = requestToRun.pop()
pm.environment.set("requestToRun", requestToRun)
val ? postman.setNextRequest(val) : postman.setNextRequest(null)
```

Now set the envirnoment variable as what you want to look for eg: run script that contains text "Regression" then set `pm.environment.set("tag","Regression")`

**Now in your collection-pre-request add:**

```
if (pm.info.requestName !== "initial request") {
    let requestToRun = pm.environment.get("requestToRun")
    let val = requestToRun.pop()
    pm.environment.set("requestToRun", requestToRun)
    val ? postman.setNextRequest(val) : postman.setNextRequest(null)
}
```

### Output:

[image]

### Example collection:

**https://www.getpostman.com/collections/73e771fe61f7781f8598**

Ran only reqeusts that has "Copy" in its name